# XHR Error 522 loading some Angular2 files

Tags: arrays, image, angular

I have issue in Angular2. Actually I am facing on load Angular2 file on run time. Its take too much time for loading and sometime gave me 522 error.

Please check image below.

[image]

Comment: Also see [Error 520: Web server is returning an unknown error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520-Web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error).

Comment: check with component spelling added in module